# Which GraphQL package to use for the Node-express app

Tags: node.js, graphql

This question might seem opinion related but I am literally Puzzled about chosing NPM package for GraphQl

TO be frank, I am just Starting with GraphQL and I opened an article, That Article asked me to install `express-graphQL`. Blindly, I installed it.

Later on, I wasn't able to comprehend the article, I saw the next article 
they were using `apollo-server-express`

Another [Article](https://www.howtographql.com/react-apollo/0-introduction/), they were  `graphql-yoga`

And then another article they are doing `npm install apollo-server graphql`

I am probably not pro like most of you who get things by reading description in npm module and while this question might be opinion related, and can someone help/guide me with graphQl package I should use.

I work with Node-Express

Comment: There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372666/apollo-server-or-graphql-server). Re: graphql-yoga, please see [here](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga/issues/382) and [here](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga#how-does-graphql-yoga-compare-to-apollo-server-and-other-tools).

Comment: To make this question less opinion-based, you could rewrite it to effectively ask "What are differences between express-graphql, apollo-server and graphql-yoga"? That's really what you want to know, and you can make up your own mind from there. However, even those kinds of questions are [generally not a good fit for SO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/16/gorilla-vs-shark/).

Comment: They all more or less do the same thing... Pick one and stick with it while learning...